# How to configure TelemetryConfiguration without dependency injection?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I use Application Insights in a webjob. Current I don't use dependency injection.
I need to configure the `TelemetryChannel` to be able to Flush the provider before exiting my webjob.
Is it possible to configure/set/inject the `TelemetryConfiguration` into the logging provider for App Insights without DI?

I use the following statement to add the logging provider.

```
    builder.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.ConnectionString = connStr).SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> configure TelemetryConfiguration without dependency injection?

To Configure Telemetry without `DI`, we need to pass Instrumentation Key or `ConnectionString` to the `TelemetryConfiguration`.

I have tried to set the Keys from `appsettings.json`

Install the NuGet Package `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web`.

[image]

***My `appsettings.json` file***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "****",
    "Instrumentationkey": "****"
  }
}
```

Thanks @[rogerpence.dev](https://rogerpence.dev/add-appsettings-json-file-to-a-c-console-app/) for the code snippet.

I have tried to follow the given code but got the below error.

```cs
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();
```

[image]

For now, I have set the keys in `Program.cs` file itself.

> Is it possible to configure/set/inject the `TelemetryConfiguration` into the logging provider for App Insights without DI?

In `Visual Studio`, right click on the solution root folder => `Add` => `Connected Service`.

[image]

- Add `Application Insights service dependency` .

[image]

***My `.csproj` file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

We have [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/console#get-started) which explains Configurating Telemetry without Dependency Injection.

***Program.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            configuration.ConnectionString = "Copy the Connectionstring from AppInsights";
            //configuration.InstrumentationKey = "****";
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
            telemetryClient.TrackTrace("Hello World!");
            telemetryClient.TrackTrace("This is the Telemetry Logs!");
            telemetryClient.Flush();
        }      
    }
}
```

***OutPut:***

[image]